# Failing to push change from AWS CodeBuild to AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have configured a CodePipeline to build and deploy a NPM project.

The pipeline doenloads the source from CodeCommit and builds it using CodeBuild. Two different stages.

However as a post version step, I want to increment the version (npm version patch).

This is failing in the CodeBuild step:
npm WARN lifecycle [project@version]~postversion: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) [project@version] git push && git push --tags /codebuild/output/src334032561/src

I've already configured the IAM service role to have git push permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this was caused by permission. Can you try creating a standalone CodeBuild project with CodeCommit repo and running a build?

Check this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251732

> CodePipeline downloads the source as a zip from the source provider rather than doing a Git clone, which means the .git folder won't be retained and git commands like the one you're running won't work.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-git-clone-for-source-actions/  I think this may work now with this option